# Classifying elements, by the value of a fixed function, using Replace

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction, replacement, filtering

Let `L` be a list of several lists. And the length of each list is less than 1000.

You can create L by

```
L = Table[ConstantArray[1, RandomInteger[999]], 100000];
```

For example, let `L` looks like

```
{a list whose length is 340,  
 a list whose length is 525,  
 a list whose length is 829,  
 a list whose length is 422, 
......}
```

What I want to get is a list of integers

```
   M = {3, 5, 8, 4,......}
```

That is, if the length of an element is
between 0~99, assign 0,
between 100~199, assign 1,
...
between 900~999, assign 9.

In fact this can be done easily by `Floor[Length[#]/100]&/@L`

**But I want to achieve it by built-in `Replace`.**

Here is the code I did my best :

```
Replace[L, Table[_?(Length[#] < 100 k &) -> k - 1 /. k -> a, {a, 1, 10}], {1}] (*code of an  interest*)
```

But there is one thing I don't like about this code algorithmically.
This code computes `Length[#]` too often.
(`Length` is very fast, so just lucky this time.
What if the function is so slow.)
**I want the `Length` to be computed only once for each element.**

I tried codes like :

```
Replace[L, Module[{Leng}, Leng = Hold[Length[#]]; 
  Table[_?(Leng < 100 k &) -> T[k] /. k -> a, {a, 10}]], {1}] (*failed code*)
```

I tried `Module,Block,With`... all failed. Can you help me?
By modifying *code of an  interest* slightly, can you show a code that computes `Length` only once for each element?

Comment: Is there a reason that you are so insistent on using Replace? Map seems like a natural thing to do here: `Quotient[Length@#, 100] & /@ L`. I would post that as the answer except that you seem to really want Replace.

Comment: Because.. If pattern1 matches then replace it to object1, If pattern2 matches then replace it to object2, If pattern3 match esthen replace it to object3... We can deal with this general problem.

Comment: Thank you, the example In my post was simple which means lucky enough to achieve the purpose with a short code. Here is my original intention and motivation : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268227/replacement-patterntest-module-related-question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
L = Table[ConstantArray[1, RandomInteger[999]], 100000];

m = Replace[L, {x_List :> Quotient[Length@x, 100]}, {1}];
```

$$\{7,2,8,8,6,5,1,5,2,1,1,3,6,7,2,4,7,2,1,8,2,3,8,6,5,2,0,7,4,9,6,3,2,4,6,5,7,7,9,9,\langle\langle 99920\rangle\rangle ,1,7,8,6,2,5,1,0,8,7,3,6,2,8,4,8,9,0,5,6,4,4,9,6,4,7,1,2,7,0,1,4,1,1,0,7,9,0,4,4\}$$

Comment: Thank you. But in fact my real motivation and intention is  about general approach : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268227/replacement-patterntest-module-related-question