# Replacement, PatternTest, Module related Question

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction, replacement, pattern-matching

Let's see how MMA handles following type of expression :

```
Replace[L, {pattTest1->rhs1, pattTest2->rhs2, pattTest3->rhs3}, {1}]
```

Specific example :

```
In[1] Replace[Range[40], {_?(#^2<10&)->1,_?(#^2<100&)->2,_?(#^2<1000&)->3}, {1}]

Out[1] {1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,
    3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40}
```

Below is what goes on in the core of MMA :

1 ) take the first element of `L` (denoted by e1)
2 ) let `#` = e1
3 ) see pattTest1, and if it contains `#`, substitute `#` with e1
4 ) see if the `pattTest1` is true
5 ) if true, replace it to `rhs1`, if not, go to `pattTest2->rhs2` step
(*Suppose that this time, it is not true*)
6 ) see `pattTest2`, and if it contains `#`, substitute `#` with e1
7 ) see if the pattTest2 is True
8 ) if true, replace it to `rhs2`, if not, go to `pattTest3->rhs3` step
(*Suppose that this time, it is true*)
9) Now e1 has been replaced to `rhs2` and everything related to e1 is completely done.
10) # is not e1 any more. Now # is not assigned any value.
11 ) take the second element of `L` (denoted by e2)
12 ) let `#` = e2
...

But I want to modify the code `In[1]` so that following additional  job is done in MMA :

**2.1 ) introduce a temporary variable m, let m = #^2. Since # is e1 now, m = (e1)^2.**
(note that (e1)^2 is evaluated, and m is set to that evaluated value)
**3.1 ) see pattTest1, and if it contains m, substitute m with (e1)^2**
**6.1 ) see pattTest2, and if it contains m, substitute m with (e1)^2**
**10.1) m is not (e1)^2 any more. Now m is not assigned any value.**

To make it easier to read :

1 ) take the first element of `L` (denoted by e1)
2 ) let `#` = e1
**2.1 ) introduce a temporary variable m, let m = #^2. Since # is e1 now, m = (e1)^2.**
3 ) see pattTest1, and if it contains `#`, substitute `#` with e1
**3.1 ) see pattTest1, and if it contains m, substitute m with (e1)^2**
4 ) see if the `pattTest1` is true
5 ) if true, replace it to `rhs1`, if not, go to `pattTest2->rhs2` step
(*Suppose that this time, it is not true*)
6 ) see `pattTest2`, and if it contains `#`, substitute `#` with e1
**6.1 ) see pattTest2, and if it contains m, substitute m with (e1)^2**
7 ) see if the pattTest2 is True
8 ) if true, replace it to `rhs2`, if not, go to `pattTest3->rhs3` step
(*Suppose that this time, it is true*)
9) Now e1 has been replaced to `rhs2` and everything related to e1 is completely done.
10) # is not e1 any more. Now # is not assigned any value.
**10.1) m is not (e1)^2 any more. Now m is not assigned any value.**
11 ) take the second element of `L` (denoted by e2)
12 ) let `#` = e2
...

I emphasize there **must not** exist step like
*5.1 ) introduce a temporary variable m, let m = (e1)^2*
just after 5 ). Because it was already done in **2.1 )**

Here is a code that I've tried and failed :

```
In[2]:= Replace[Range[40], Module[{m},m=#^2;{_?(m<10&)->1,
_?(m<100&)->2,_?(m<1000&)->3}], {1}]

Out[2]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40}
```

Finally I want to emphasize that, this time, my question is not about solving a specific problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your attempt fails is that at the time the `Function` is applied to its arguments, `m` has not yet been replaced by `#^2`, so the `#` is not replaced by the argument of the function:

```
Module[{m = #^2}, m &[1]]
(* #1^2 *)
```

Having said that, it wouldn't work the way you want anyway: You need to "capture" the value of `#` at the point of the `Module`, if you want to ensure that the computation only happens once. That means that you need to insert another layer of evaluation between the application of the individual rules and the initial visiting of the element. So you need "Visit element 1" -> "Compute (Element 1)^2" -> "Try to apply rules". This is not doable with a single application of `Replace`.

With this in mind, here's one way (Ignoring whether this results in readable code):

```
Replace[Range[40], x_ :> Module[{m = x^2},
   Replace[
    x, {_?(m < 10 &) -> 1, _?(m < 100 &) -> 2, _?(m < 1000 &) -> 3}]
   ],
 {1}
 ]
(* {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, \
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40} *)
```

Or written using `Map` for the outer layer (which I find more readable):

```
Map[Module[{m = #^2},
   Replace[#, {_?(m < 10 &) -> 1, _?(m < 100 &) -> 2, _?(m < 1000 &) ->
       3}]
   ] &,
 Range[40]
 ]
(* same output *)
```

Here is an alternative that I would prefer in this specific use case:

```
Map[
 With[{m = #^2},
   Which[
    m < 10, 1,
    m < 100, 2,
    m < 1000, 3,
    True, #
    ]
   ] &,
 Range[40]
 ]
(* same output *)
```

Effectively, if you're using `Replace`-like functions to test only for non-structural properties, you should use `Which` or similar instead. (The reason being that all you're doing in your replacement rules is to apply a `PatternTest`, which leads to a lot of syntax & runtime overhead)

Comment: Thank you very much! I tested performance also about the problem https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268208/classifying-elements-by-the-value-of-a-fixed-function-using-replace

Comment: And the result is : Original long code(not using module) : 0.37s,
Lukas Lang's 1st and 2nd code :1.5s
3rd code: 0.35s

Comment: So, I strongly recommend to use 3rd code(using `Which`), it is very powerful and fast! It can do things like `Replace[L, {pattTest1->rhs1, pattTest2->rhs2, pattTest3->rhs3}, {1}]` + module concept + even faster.